# Process HTML, update and then save in Ghost

Tags: javascript, rss, ghost-blog, podcast

I’m running Ghost ([ghost.org](http://ghost.org), v2.1.4) with Casper (default theme), and I want to post podcasts. As of now, there’s no good way to do that. Here’s what I’m trying to accomplish:

1. When a post contains a link to an .mp3 file, this post becomes a podcast
2. Some code to be injected right above this URL and will display an
   HTML5-compatible player (say, `wavesurfer.js`)
3. URL itself gets updated to a proper link: “Download Episode #xxx”
4. A proper `enclosure` tag gets created and injected into the post as invisible code (?)
5. This `enclosure` becomes available for this particular post in RSS feed for further podcast syndication
6. This updated post gets saved back to the database

I’m not really sure about the best way to approach this. I’ve been able to make points 1 through 3 work with Ghost's `content` helper, so whenever there’s an .mp3 url in the post, it becomes a media player with the download link below.

How do I add an enclosure to the post so it appears in the RSS? And what’s the proper way to take this whole post object afterwards and post it back to the database as an update (I’m using MySQL at the time)?

Any suggestions/pointers are very welcome, as documentation is limited and not always clear about accomplishing this kind of thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure if what you're looking for is possible with the current extension points. And, like for all problems that are not possible, I have an impossible solution :)

With the newest version of Ghost, like 2.1.4, you can enable Zapier, under "Apps". This gives you the option to create hooks (called "zaps") that are basically http-based callbacks. Like the one the can share new post on twitter automatically.

You could create your own little service, like an Amazon Lambda or Azure Functions service. You can set up a zap (there is already a prebuilt one for Amazon Lambda, but you should be able to create one for Azure Functions or even just for any simple HTTP service) that is called whenever a new post is created and this forwards the call to the Amazon Lambda or Azure Function (or your own service). Then, inside the called service you can connect to your MySql database, query for and modify the post and save it back.

So basically the workflow goes like this:

1. You create a post
2. The post is saved, this triggers a zap that calls let's say Amazon Lambda
3. Inside the lambda, you query for the post from your MySQL DB
4. You modify the post and save it back

I know this is not ideal and seems way complicated, but at least it is fully automated.

Another option would be to create and register a custom ghost helper. This is basically a piece of Node.Js code that can be referenced like the `{{content}}` and other helpers and can be programmed to output any arbitrary piece of html into the template. I'm currently editing a series of blogposts about the custom helpers that I have created for my Ghost blog,  but in the meantime, you can check out the [associated Github repository](https://github.com/conwid/GhostHelpers) for the code and the [wiki](https://github.com/conwid/GhostHelpers/wiki) for the most-important know-how. Again, this solution is quite convoluted and everything is based on unsupported, undocumented features.

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion! I've also got some ideas from the Ghost developers involving custom template for `podcast` category posts (media player for mp3s + `enclosure` tag embedding) and dynamic route for these posts (RSS generation using custom template). Not sure which way is better, but it seems like, thanks to you and Aileen, I'm onto something! :)

Comment: I'd be very interested to see what can you come up with. When you are ready and you are allowed to publish the custom theme or code or whatever (or even during development), I would definitely check it out.